# How to pass a question mark express router api to update sql

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, express

I want to update a varchar field (String) using and End-Point Api (Express NodeJS) but I have problem went I pass invalid inputs like question mark.

Express End-Point:

```
router.get("/updateField/:table/:field/:value/:num/:postid/", function(req, res) {

    connection.query(

        'UPDATE '+ req.params.table +' SET ' + req.params.field +' = '+JSON.stringify(req.params.value) +' where language ='+ req.params.num +' and post_id ='+req.params.postid
```

This code work fine:

http://localhost:3001/api/updateField/posts/TITLE/When/1/1

But this NOT WORK:

http://localhost:3001/api/updateField/posts/TITLE/When?/1/1

I send the request from react like this:

```
fetch(
      "http://localhost:3001/api/updateField/" +
        table +
        "/" +
        field +
        "/" +
        value +
        "/" +
        lenguage +
        "/" +
        post_id
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript function `encodeURIComponent()` to escape special characters in URL parameters.

For example try this on your browser console and you'll get an idea:

```
console.log(
      "http://localhost:3001/api/updateField/" +
        table +
        "/" +
        field +
        "/" +
        encodeURIComponent(value) +
        "/" +
        lenguage +
        "/" +
        post_id
    );
console.log(encodeURIComponent("When?"));
```

You will see that **"When?"** is replaced with **"When%3F"** in URL.
In Node.Js, you'll receive parameter value as string **"When?"**.

To know more about `encodeURIComponent()`, refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: +1 work perfect! 
but I was supposed to do a decode on the express GET, but is not necesary.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :)